# How to find out if 2 cells contain texts/numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I come out with a formula which gives me...

- if cell A1 contains SOMETHING and cell B1 contains something, equate to "OKAY"
- and if cell A1 contains something and cell B1 is empty/blank, equate to "NOT OKAY"

Cell A1 MUST contain something, what formula can i use to combine both together?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Kindly read the [FAQ] -- it is expected that questions here relate to programming. This question should probably be asked on [su]. Also, it isn't necessary to preface the question with the name of the program, that's what tags are for.

Comment: chuck your attempt on Sean

Answer (score 0):

1. you google "[excel formula empty](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel%20formula%20empty)" + do some other research
2. you figure out how it works and come up with your own formula, e.g.:

   ```
   =IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1);ISBLANK(B1)); "NOT OKAY"; "OKAY")
   =IF(ISBLANK(A1) = ISBLANK(B1); "OKAY"; "NOT OKAY")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> what formula can I use to combine both together?

You can use COUNTA(). For example...

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1,B1)=2,"OKAY","NOT OKAY")
```

Answer (score 0):

ok (without sneaking a view of the other answers)

`=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"NOT OK",IF(ISBLANK(B1),"NOT OK","OK"))`